# Apex Trigger to Update Contact Detail field field Based on account information field

Tags: trigger

I am trying to create a trigger for update in Contact field(custom field name is Type). when I will update in Account information Section(Field name is Type for Ex. Prospect -> Customer-Direct.).

Answer (score 2):

By far the simplest way to have a field on `Contact` that reflects the value of a field in `Account` is to make the `Contact` field a [formula field](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) that automatically presents the value from the `Account` field.